# Why Sqoop uses 4 mappers by default

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

While using sqoop in my day to day activity, I don't get why the developer's of sqoop chosen default number of mappers as 4. As there is provision for increasing or decreasing the number of mappers. But the question is why there are 4 mappers by default, is there any logic behind that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sqoop is a retired Apache project, by the way. Might not be worth continuing to use "day to day"